# LDAP: how to search for user with windows id

Tags: java, ldap

I need to authenticate a user using the windows ID which is not the same as the "user name".  For example: windows ID is jSmith but the user name is "Joe Smith".  I need to find Joe Smith based on the windows ID and then check if he is a member of a certain group.

I'm assuming or hoping that the windows ID is an attribute of the user but I'm new to the LDAP and don't know how to search for a specific attribute in all users.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming when you say Windows ID for authentication your LDAP is actually Active Directory.

If you just want to find the user by LanId in the Active Directory:

1. connecting to the Active using an Admin/service account username and password.
2. search for user with following filter: 
   `"(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + searchUsername + "))"`

If you want to authenticate the user:

```
Hashtable environment = new Hashtable();
environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");// can make it variable, not needed so far
environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple"); // can make it variable, not needed so far
environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username + "@" + domain); // This is specific to AD
environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

return new InitialLdapContext(environment, null);
```

If the above code is executed successfully without exception, that means user provided correct username/password

Comment: Okay, I did this search filter and it worked great. (Obviously some terms have made up names, but you get the idea). "(&(ObjectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=jSmith)(memberOf=CN=Blah,OU=Company-Users,DC=BlahBlah,DC=local))" Now I would like to add the password to the filter. Anyone know what the "key" of the password is? For example (passwordKey="MyDogName13") where passwordKey is... On this same topic... Is there any way to get a list of available attributes (key names) back? Thanks.

Comment: Even if you could retrieve a password and then do authentication by matching, I would recommend using `bind authentication` as mentioned above. I have created a simple api to use Active Directory for Authentication and Attribute retrieval which you can get from here : https://github.com/kdabir/active-directory-lookup (I've just checked in today, will write a README soon)